# Kotlin + Hilt: Cannot inject repository class into service class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm working on a multi-module Kotlin app and I'm not being able to inject a repository class (located in one module) into its corresponding service class (located in a different module).

TrackService:

```
class TrackService {

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: TrackRepository

    init {
        setDependencies()
    }

    private fun setDependencies() {
        val repository = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
            aw.context,
            Dependencies.ProvideTrackRepository::class.java
        )
        this.repository = repository.TrackRepository()
    }
}
```

Dependencies provider class for repository:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class Dependencies {

    @EntryPoint
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    interface ProvideTrackRepository {
        fun TrackRepository(): TrackRepository
    }
}
```

Service provider for the view:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Dependencies {

    @Provides
    fun provideTrackService(): TrackService {
        return TrackService()
    }
}
```

And usage in a view:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(),
    IActionListeners, IImageListeners, OnListFragmentInteractionListener
{
    @Inject
    lateinit var trackService: TrackService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val track = trackService.getTrack(1)
        ...
    }
}
```

Curiously the app builds just fine, but when I run the app I get the next Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.xxx.xxx.app.DaggerAWApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl to com.xxx.xxx.injector.Dependencies$ProvideTrackRepository
```

### Edit 1 (new attempt)

I've also tried:

```
class TrackService {

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: TrackRepository

    ...
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class Dependencies {

    @Provides
    fun provideTrackRepository(): TrackRepository {
        return TrackRepository()
    }
}
```

But it's complaining about "repository variable has not been initialized".

Comment: `class TrackService @Inject constructor(private val repository: TrackRepository) { ...` instead of EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication and ProvideTrackRepository?

Comment: Hello and thanks for replying @IR42. Constructor injection in the first thing I always try before ending in EntryPoints, but in this case I also need a "Provides" to provide TrackService like this: Provides fun provideTrackService(): TrackService { return TrackService() } and If I set TrackService to use constructor injection I don't know then how to supply the TrackService constructor arguments in the mentioned provider function.

Comment: you don't need `@Provides fun provideTrackService(): TrackService ` if you have `class TrackService @Inject constructor(...`

Comment: Hi and thanks again @IR42. If I haven't done #Inject constructor for TrackService is because I'm using it in an activity, and -as far as I know- activities cannot be constructor injected (I've tried though, but they cannot be instantiated then, it complains about ActivityXXXX not having a zero argument constructor). Said this, I was "forced" to use fields injection and -at the same time- to use "Provides" to provide the dependency.

Comment: Field injection is only needed for android components, because the system creates them, `@AndroidEntryPoint` helps you with this. For the rest of your custom classes, you can and should use constructor injection (or @Provides for classes that you can't change, for example OkHttpClient), it allows the dagger to create them. You should read more about hilt and dagger https://dagger.dev/hilt/,  https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes